# Draw ticks on negative part of the line chart d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to place ticks for negative part of D3.js line chart. Somehow it only shows for positive part of the chart.

```
  y = d3.scale.linear().domain([d3.min(data, function (d) { return d.TOTL_ACNT_BAL; }), d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.TOTL_ACNT_BAL; }) + 700]).range([height, 0]),
            yAxisTicks = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
                                      .ticks(12)
                                      .tickSize(width)
                                      .tickFormat('')
                                      .orient('right'),
```

Fiddle attached here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/tpnc2zL5/

Comment: Your jsfiddle is giving me errors.

Comment: just found the issue. I was not parsing JSON data in integer.